# What is the best way to track memory management while testing my iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management

While developing my app I have come to realize that the majority of my app crashes have arisen from poor memory management.

I understand I can print or log retain counts through NSLog (@"retain count is:%d",[myInstance retainCount]);

But isn't there a better, less manual method? Possibly a visual representation of your objects and instances?

**answered. Cheers, Adam & Jason. :-)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Leaks and Object Allocation tools through XCode.

```
Run > Start with Performance Tool > ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, I would highly recommend using clang to do a static memory analysis of your code.  It won't catch every memory-management error, but it does catch quite a lot.  If your chief problem seems to come from memory management errors, clang will go a long way toward finding those errors.  Clang is free, at http://clang.llvm.org/

Answer (score 2):

As Adam suggests, Instruments is a very useful tool for these kinds of things. It's fairly easy to use, but can be a bit overwhelming at first. I suggest perusing the [Instruments User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html) as you get started. It's pretty easy to follow and is helpful until you've used Instruments for a while. Even without reading the guide, however, Instruments is still far easier and more intuitive than littering your code with NSLog() calls and trying to parse the output yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also find the [NSZombie](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) trick useful for tracking down cases of over-release objects.

Basically the link describes a 'trick' so that release'd objects get replaced by NSZombie objects which if they get released again throw exceptions.

You can then use [Instruments](http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/index.php/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/) to track back to where the object was allocated.